# java : generating xpath using string matcher regex

Tags: java, regex, xpath

I want to generate xPath from html file. So far, I have been succeded to store Html source in a String and generating basic xpath using matcher regex as follows:-

```
 String text   = "<html><body><table><tr id=\"x\"><td>abc</td><td></td><td>xyz</td></tr></table></body></html>";

//I want xpath till label "xyz"
         String unwanted= "xyz";  

//so splitting  and storing needed String 
        String[] neededString=text.split(unwanted);

        String a="";

//pattern for extracting tags
        String patternString1 = "<(.+?)>";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString1);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(neededString[0]);

        while(matcher.find()) {

             a=a.concat(matcher.group(1)+"/");
        System.out.println(a);

    }
```

This code works for basic tag Structure without multiple child nodes like multiple `<td>`'s in `<tr>`. Can anyone improve my above code to include xpath generation for multiple childs and also for capturing attrributes like Ids,Class etc.

Any help is much appreciated.
    Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why exactly do you think that using regular expressions will help you here? Use a proper HTML parser, doing this with regex is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not so Accurate for Extracting the Html content.

Use [**Jsoup**](http://jsoup.org/) Html Parser

```
public static void main(String[] args){
       String html = "<html><body><table><tr id=\"x\"><td>abc</td><td></td>" +
            "<td>xyz</td></tr></table></body></html>";

       Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

       for (Element table : doc.select("table")) {
             for (Element row : table.select("tr[id=x]")) {
                Elements tds = row.select("td)");
                System.out.println(tds.get(2).text());
             }
        }

      }
```